# Mismatch between Java version used for compilation and Java used for running

Tags: java, compilation

I am having the following error when I try to run an application I built:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
MyApp/MainApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file 
version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

Now.. when I check which version of Java I have installed I see that I installed the jdk-13.0.1 which is the latest version and contains also the JRE that I need. Also in my environment path variables I point to the bin of its installation folder. Can you please help me understanding what am I missing?

Edit:
The app is a spring boot app. I go into the target folder where the MyApp.jar (as result of the building process) is located. Once there I run the command:

```
Java -jar MyApp.jar
```

In my environment variables into PATH I have: *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin*

And also the JAVA_HOME points to *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1*

Comment: How do you run this app? (be precise. Explain exactly how you're doing it, with the exact and complete command).

Comment: OK. So what is the output of `Java -version`?

Comment: Java -version was giving an old version indeed somehow.
I noticed that in the "Path" of the system variables there was one about "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath" . I removed it. I also removed any java exe file from C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath , at the end I reinstalled again the  JDK-13 and now it works properly! Thanks for redirecting me to the right way guys!